How do I do significance testing in this experiment?
We have an internal search engine system similar to google. On a default config A, if we give a query, it will give 1000 results with a rank. If the same query was given again, it will again give 1000 results with a rank but not necessarily the same results or results with same rank. For ex, 25% of the results can be different. Now I use a different config B which in theory should perform exactly as config A. Even within config B, if I give the same query twice, x% of the results can be different. I want to test

if variation in results observed between different runs on same query within config A is similar to variation in results observed within config B
Since config A and B should perform exactly same, I want to test if difference in results between config A and B is similar to variation of results observed within config A or config B.

"variation in result" mean if the "result + rank" between different job runs doesn't match.
For this analysis, I took 5000 queries and pulled 1000 results for each query from three different job runs with config A and three different job runs with config B. So in total I have results from 6 job runs. My dataset looks like this



query
search_rank
result_url
config
job_run




who is pluto
1
some_url.com/1
A
1


who is pluto
1
some_url.com/1
A
2


who is pluto
1
some_url.com/2
A
3


who is bruno
1
another_url.com/5
A
1


who is bruno
1
another_url.com/6
A
2


who is bruno
1
another_url.com/6
A
3


who is pluto
1
some_url.com/2
B
1


who is pluto
1
some_url.com/1
B
2


who is pluto
1
some_url.com/1
B
3


who is bruno
1
another_url.com/6
B
1


who is bruno
1
another_url.com/5
B
2


who is bruno
1
another_url.com/6
B
3



Below is the f-test I did. But I am not sure if it's accurate
1. to answer my 1st question
def calc_within_config_variance(config_group):
    rank_diffs = []
    job_combinations = list(combinations(config_group['job_run'].unique(), 2))
    
    for run1, run2 in job_combinations:
        results_run1 = config_group[config_group['job_run'] == run1].set_index('rank')['result_url'].sort_index()
        results_run2 = config_group[config_group['job_run'] == run2].set_index('rank')['result_url'].sort_index()

        # Calculate rank difference count
        diff_count = (results_run1 != results_run2).sum()
        rank_diffs.append(diff_count / len(results_run1))  # Proportion of differing ranks

    return pd.Series(rank_diffs).var() if rank_diffs else 0

variance_df = df.groupby(
    ['uid', 'query', 'config']
).apply(calc_within_config_variance).reset_index(name='within_config_variance')

variance_A = variance_df[variance_df['config'] == 'A']['within_config_variance']
variance_B = variance_df[variance_df['config'] == 'B']['within_config_variance']

f_statistic = variance_A.mean()/ variance_B.mean()
dof1, dof2 = len(variance_A) - 1, len(variance_B) - 1
p_value = 1 - f_test.cdf(f_statistic, dof1, dof2) if dof1 > 0 and dof2 > 0 else 1

# Step 3: Output results
print(f"F-statistic: {f_statistic}")
print(f"P-value: {p_value}")

if p_value < 0.05:
    print("Significant difference in rank variances between within-configurations A and B.")
else:
    print("No significant difference in rank variances between within-configurations A and B.")

2. to answer the 2nd question
def calc_between_config_variance(query_group):
    rank_diffs = []
    job_runs = query_group['job_run'].unique()
    
    for job_run1 in job_runs:
        # Separate results by configuration
        for job_run2 in job_runs:
            results_A = query_group[
                (query_group['config'] == 'A') &
                (query_group['job_run'] == job_run1)
            ].set_index('rank')['result_url'].sort_index()
            results_B = query_group[
                (query_group['config'] == 'B') &
                (query_group['job_run'] == job_run2)
            ].set_index('rank')['result_url'].sort_index()

            # Calculate rank differences between configurations
            rank_diff_count = (results_A != results_B).sum()
            rank_diffs.append(rank_diff_count / len(results_A))  # Proportion of differing ranks

    return pd.Series(rank_diffs).var() if rank_diffs else 0

between_configs_variance_df = df.groupby(
    ['uid', 'query']
).apply(calc_between_config_variance).reset_index(name='between_config_variance')

between_configs_variance = between_configs_variance_df["between_config_variance"]

f_statistic = between_configs_variance.mean()/ variance_B.mean()
dof1, dof2 = len(between_configs_variance) - 1, len(variance_B) - 1
p_value = 1 - f_test.cdf(f_statistic, dof1, dof2) if dof1 > 0 and dof2 > 0 else 1

print(f"F-statistic: {f_statistic}")
print(f"P-value: {p_value}")

if p_value < 0.05:
    print("Significant difference in rank variances between between-config of A and B and within-configuration of B.")
else:
    print("No Significant difference in rank variances between between-config of A and B and within-configuration of B.")

